# One promocode may be used only once

Tags: sql, logic, backend

I have tables as on img. I want every promo code generaated with per_user_once = 1 paramether to be used only once. For example I have a promo code 123456 for which adv_action.valid_count = 5 and adv_action.per_user_once = 5. In my case this code can be used by different users total 5 times. But I want this promo code could be used only by 1 person. What is your idea about that ? How would you do it ? What is your logic/suggestion ? Please suggest your idea based on my tables. I hope I explained correctly.

adv_action table

[image: adv_action]
promo_code table

[image: promo_code]

adv_action_business table

[image: adv_action_business]

Comment: If you want a promo code to be used only once per user, then you'll need to store the details of the usage somewhere. For example, a table with (promo_code, user_id)... and make that a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh, but there is no any attempt, because I have no strong idea about that. I show ed the table which currently  I have. And I think for experienced one, like you, it will easy to understand my question based on my example.

Comment: @TheImpaler please could you give little more explanation.